# Finding simple modules in fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I am struggling with finding all simple are modules for general rings

i know that the simple modules of R correspond with the simple modules of R/rad(R), where rad(R) is the Jacobson radical but i am struggling to apply this to say polynomial rings over complex C[X]

or defining a ring of real valued CTS functions

any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: All simple $\mathbb{C}[x]$ modules are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]/M$, where $M$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x]$. All maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are of the form $<x-a>$, where $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Thus all simple modules are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, with $x$ acting as multiplication by $a$. In general the question is too difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very difficult problem that has no known general solution. The following [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=vXh1MtvQr_8C&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=simple+modules+over+polynomial+rings&source=bl&ots=d3-fFtxpuO&sig=o00YZPluhi4zCmgyIY_WEluqiMA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pOpaVLLnMoHAiAKm1IDIBg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=simple%20modules%20over%20polynomial%20rings&f=false), execise 17G asks the reader to prove that there are infinitely many pairwise non-isomorphic unfaithful simple modules over a polynomial ring in one variable with coefficients in a division ring. If you are interested in studying the simple modules over a particular family of rings I recommend looking up literature on the specific rings if you are having trouble classifying the simple modules on your own.